# Mvc 3 validation of property that throws an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a property on my Model Class that performs a type conversion as follows:

Model:

```
public class TimeClass
{
    private int timeInSeconds;

    [Required]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string Timer
    {
       get {
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0,0,(int)timeInSeconds);
            return ts.ToString(@"mm\:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       }
       set {
          try {
             var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, @"mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
             timeInSeconds= Convert.ToInt32(ts.TotalSeconds);
          }
          catch {
             //Is it possible to add a validation error to the modelstate here
          }  
       }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
  string[] whitelist = new[] {"Id", "Timer" };

  if (TryUpdateModel(quiz, whitelist))
  {
    //Save to Repo
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { Id = Id });
  }
  return View(tc);
}
```

What is the appropriate pattern to add an appropriate ModelError if the TimeSpan.Parse throws an exception?
Currently it will give the generic error "The value "xxx" is invalid".  How can I customize this to return a specific error?

Comment: What is ClockTime? Another property of the model?

Comment: ClockTime is a backing variable, I edited the question to make clearer.  Changed ClockTime to timeInSeconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than putting the try catch within your model, you could move the error handling to your controller code. For example if the tryupdatemodel throws an exception you could add a custom model error:

```
TimeClass model = new TimeClass();
string[] whitelist = new[] {"Id", "Timer" };
try
{
    UpdateModel(model);

    //Save to Repo
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { Id = Id });
}
catch
{
    // Generate error
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Model Error Here");

    return View(tc);
}
```

Comment: TryUpdateModel does not throw an exception. The model binder catches the exception and puts a "The value 'xxx' is invalid" error message in ModelState.

Comment: Sorry, I had intended to update that to use UpdateModel instead.